# Split URL into it's different parts VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, url

I would like to split a URL into its different components, similar to the location object in JavaScript. The parts I would like are: hash, host, hostname, pathname, port, protocol, and query string. The URL I would like to split is: `http://localhost:8080/settings/settings.php?setting=layout&value=normal#appearance`.

Currently, I have:

```
Dim url as String = "http://localhost:8080/settings/settings.php?setting=layout&value=normal#appearance"
Dim protocol as String = url.Split("://")(0)
Dim hash = url.Split("#")(1)
Dim query as String = url.Split("?")(1).Split("#")(0)
```

But I don't think it is efficient, or reliable. I also do not know how to get the rest of the parts.

Is there a more efficient way of getting the query string? And how can I split the URL into the parts I described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the built-in class [**`System.Uri`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx), which can do all the parsing for you automatically:

```
Dim url as String = "http://localhost:8080/settings/settings.php?setting=layout&value=normal#appearance"
Dim uri as New Uri(url)
```

With an instance of `Uri` you should be able to retrieve all those parts easily.

```
Dim protocol as String = uri.Scheme     ' http
Dim host as String = uri.Host           ' localhost
Dim port as Integer = uri.Port           ' 8080
Dim path as String = uri.AbsolutePath   ' /settings/settings.php
Dim querystring as String = uri.Query   ' ?setting=layout&value=normal
Dim hash as String = uri.Fragment       ' #appearance
```

Comment: This Uri object appears to be recognized in C#, but not Excel VBA. :(